# Sitecore license with oracle key

Tags: oracle, sitecore, licensing

I have Sitecore license and oracle key. As per sitecore installation guide:

```
You should have the Oracle specific license keys in your license file to
run Sitecore with the Oracle database: Sitecore.Oracle and Sitecore.FireDB.
```

Does Sitecore have to generate license with oracle key or can I edit license file and put it there myself? Does anybody know what format should it have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not self edit the license file, ask at your local Sitecore office.

Also there are some limitations, Today only support for CMS only mode.
See [Sitecore Compatibility Table](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/087164)